# Is it possible to bind multiple event handlers for the same event to a widget? Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to bind the same key to the same widget but with different events but whenever I do this, the first event just gets ignored.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

c = StringVar()
c2 = StringVar()

def myfunction():
    c.set('Hello World')

def myfunction2():
    c2.set('Hello World, again')

root.bind('<Enter>', lambda event: myfunction()
label = Label(root, textvariable=c, bg='#0f0f0f', fg='white',
                       font=('@Yu Gothic Light', 12))
label.place(x=4, y=160)


root.bind('<Enter>', lambda event: myfunction2())
label2 = Label(root, textvariable=c2, bg='#0f0f0f', fg='white',
                       font=('@Yu Gothic Light', 12))  
label2.place(x=4, y=190)
# label 2 doesn't show anything and just gets ignored

root.mainloop()
```

What I'm trying to do is to set a label to a certain text when the cursor touches the root window.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior of `bind` is to *replace* existing bindings.

If you want to add them, you need to use the `add` argument.

```
root.bind('<Enter>', lambda event: myfunction2(), add="+")
```